# How to print text using xpath and Javascript executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying perform my automation on iOS device.
When I am trying following code,

```
WebElement elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell//*[@name=\"price\"]"));

String string = elements.getText();

System.out.println(string);
```

It is not printing the output but it is passing the test.

Can any one please help me to do the same thing using javascript executor.

Comment: in appium inspector, it shows the text in which part--- name, value or in label?

Comment: @noor I have tried that, some how it is not picking up the xpath given. So I am trying it using javascript executor.

Comment: add an image of ur appium inspector with that element

Answer (score 0):

use like below:

```
WebElement elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("use right xpath from inspector"));

String string = elements.getAttribute("value");//if the text is shown in value
```

or

```
String string = elements.getAttribute("name");//if the text is shown in name
```

or

```
String string = elements.getAttribute("label");//if shown in lable

System.out.println(string);
```

u may try this:

```
driver.findElementByName("price");
```

But u must have to pick the right xpath from appium inspector.

Comment: if u want to use execute script, u have to add the image of appium inspector

Comment: i hava add one extra method in my answer pls check this and let me know

Comment: Yeah I also think your xpath is wrong. Might be you are missing a tag. If possible please add hierarchy screen shot